# C++: append __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ to c string

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am trying to append `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to the c-string prefix at compile time. But it fails to compile. Whereas if I do it with `__FILE__` then it doesn't fail.

```
const char* s1= "Prefix" __FILE__;            // works
const char* s2= "Prefix" __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; // compilation error

error: expected ',' or ';' before '__PRETTY_FUNCTION__'
const char* s2 = "Prefix" __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am using gcc and clang.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [**6.10.8.1 Mandatory macros**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8) of the C standard, `__FILE__` is a string literal:

> `__FILE__`
>       The presumed name of the current source file (a character string literal).

Similar language can be found in paragraph 1 of **16.8 Predefined macro names** of [the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf).

whereas, per [**6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers**, paragraph 1 of the C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.2.2p1) `__func__` is an identifier:

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator
>   as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function
>   definition, the declaration
>
> ```
>       static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```

Paragraph 8 of **8.4.1 General** of [the C++ standard states](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> The function-local predefined variable `__func__` is defined as if a
>   definition of the form
>
> ```
>     static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> had been provided, where
>   *function-name*
>   is an implementation-defined string. It is unspecified whether such
>   a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program.

Assuming the GCC extension `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is implemented as the standard `__func__`, as an actual identifier it can't be concatenated with a string literal.

Answer (score 6):

From the GCC [documentation for `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html):

> [`__func__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`] are variables, not preprocessor macros, and may not be used to initialize char arrays or be concatenated with string literals.